# Drawing a circle on top of a square already created - pygame

Tags: python, pygame, geometry

I'm currently trying to make a game of checkers in pygame which would require getting the pieces in the right square on the board however, when i run this only the board will appear but none of the piece. In this program I've only done the black pieces which will just be a plain black circle. I wondering if anyone knows how to draw the circles on top of the squares that have already been drawn.

```
def drawPlayer1Circle(row):
    if (row<=2):
        return True
    else:
        return False
def drawPlayer2Circle(row):
    if (row>=5) and (row%2!=0 and column%2==0) and (row%2!=0 and column%2!=0):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def drawCircle():

    pygame.draw.circle(screen,BLACK,[((MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN)+xDistanceFromEdge,
        (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN,
        WIDTH/2,
            HEIGHT/2],WIDTH/2)
def drawBoard(BLACK,WHITE):# Draw the grid
    for row in range(8):
        for column in range(8):
            if row%2==0 and column%2==0:
                color = BLACK
            if row%2!=0 and column%2==0:
                color = WHITE
                if drawPlayer1Circle(row)==True:
                    drawCircle()
            if row%2==0 and column%2!=0:
                color=WHITE
            if row%2!=0 and column%2!=0:
                color= BLACK
                if drawPlayer1Circle(row)==True:
                    drawCircle()
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,
                             color,
                             [((MARGIN + WIDTH) * column + MARGIN)+xDistanceFromEdge,
                              (MARGIN + HEIGHT) * row + MARGIN,
                              WIDTH,
                              HEIGHT])
```

Comment: Enlighten us about what you tried else thus-far by editing it into your question... its called "showing effort" and is a good medicine against down-voters.

Comment: Please post a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy and run, but try to reduce it to the minimum first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are drawing the circles before the board so the board is being drawn over the top. Additionally, you should really pass `row` and `column` to the function `drawCircle` and this section of code is being needlessly repeated:

```
        if row%2==0 and column%2==0:
            color = BLACK
        if row%2!=0 and column%2==0:
            color = WHITE
            if drawPlayer1Circle(row)==True:
                drawCircle()
```